# What about EasyBCD?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I just edited the tag `easybcd` and after I found some questions like [How to install EasyBCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120642/how-to-install-easybcd) or [Can't get bootloader to work using easyBCD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243789/cant-get-bootloader-to-work-using-easybcd/243844#243844). These questions have the answer in Windows.

We know that EasyBCD is a software utility for Windows. Would it be appropriate to ask EasyBCD related questions on Ask Ubuntu? Or is better to migrate them to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If its about using or repairing a Ubuntu system, or fixing the issues caused by a broken boot loader while trying to install Ubuntu, why not?

Does not matter if the software you are using is Windows based, as long as you use it for something you are doing or did with Ubuntu.

I would include as acceptable:

- Fix multi boot systems;
- Fix boot after installing Ubuntu or Windows after installing Ubuntu;

I would not include as acceptable (off-topic)

- Fix Windows after removing Ubuntu;

The line is small here, help where you can, but migration of anything that has the easybcd tag should not become a rule.

Comment: Also, we cross many deltas with Stack Overflow, Unix and Linux, Super User, and Server Fault. Just because there's some level of duplication doesn't really matter. If it's about Ubuntu and the user chose to ask here, we should respect that.

Comment: Why would "Fix Windows after removing Ubuntu" be off-topic? Thanks for trying Ubuntu, sorry things didn't work out, suckers!?

Comment: Re. my comment, many users will delete the ubuntu partition when removing it, leaving their computer unbootable. Helping them install the Windows bootloader should be on-topic. (Or if grub smeared the windows bootsector, it should be okay to help them fix it).

Comment: @bcbc I would say it is border edge since you can try Ubuntu without installing it, also we use Ubuntu (< assumption here), so we are not the experts in Windows, the people in Super User might be more of a help than us. Again, not trying to make rules or strict ideas, I am just against making easybcd off-topic for the site and worthy of migrating those posts.

Comment: I think there are many dual booters here who can answer these. We are also more likely to know what the problems caused by dual booting Ubuntu are compared to many Windows users, who have never needed to understand the 'magic' of how their Windows boots up every day. I agree there is a limit to Windows issues e.g. BSOD and problems not caused by grub.

Comment: "not trying to make rules or strict ideas, I am just against making easybcd off-topic for the site and worthy of migrating those posts." Also http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3811/is-it-considered-on-topic-if-a-user-needs-help-to-get-back-only-windows-after-h/3812#comment5670_3811.

Comment: I am not against you, but think we should focus on what is asked here.